# scroll gridView over the button

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-imagebutton

I want to scroll the `gridView` and the image buttons are in front of the view how to scroll the `gridView` over the buttons.

[image]

.XML file is here...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.hamidhameed.CamScanner.Fragments.Fragment_thumb">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BtnCamera"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_camera"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BtnMedia"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="110dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BtnMedia"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_photo"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BtnCamera"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/BtnCamera"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
```

Comment: you can use floating action buttons as your buttons

Comment: can you provide xml layout here ? so it will be more clear

Comment: yes of course..!!

Comment: @KrishnaJ please explain how to use the floating button for this purpose.

Comment: you can get more idea from this library of floating action button : https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Comment: @KrishnaJ i already checked this but gridView is connected only with one button